# How to recognize the last page of viewpager and automatically redirect to first page when swiped

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

My title is my problem, I have 3 pages in a viewPager. How do I redirect to first page when I **swipe** on the last page in viewPager?

```
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        int x  = position;
        Log.i("ON Possition",Integer.Tostring(x));
        if(x == 3){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(x);
            Log.i("ON last Possition",Integer.Tostring());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't move to first page smoothly from last page.

read below code. we should fake item count.

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;

    public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context= context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (tList != null && tList.size() > 1) {
            return tList.size() * MAX_PAGE; // simulate infinite by big number of products
        } else {
            return tList.size();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        int position;
        if (tList != null && tList.size() > 1) {
            position = super.getItemPosition(object) % tList.size(); // use modulo for infinite cycling
            return position;
        } else {
            return super.getItemPosition(object);
        }

    }

    public int getItemPosition(int index) {
        int position;
        if (tList!= null && tList.size() > 1) {
            position = index % tList.size(); // use modulo for infinite cycling
            return position;
        } else {
            return index;
        }

    }


}
```